# Вводное слово во вставке

Tags: пунктуация

> Женщины – красивые по крайней мере – редко бывают просты в общении.

Такое предложение есть здесь: [синтаксис и семантика в пунктуации](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200401403).

> (ПО КРАЙНЕЙ МЕРЕ, вводное выражение. Слова «по крайней мере» следует выделять знаками препинания в том случае, если они расположены после слов, с которыми связаны по смыслу.)

Почему здесь вводное сочетание "по крайней мере" не выделяется запятыми. Во вставках вводные выделяются запятыми: Его жена – должно быть, забывшая о нашей предварительной договоренности – встретила нас в самом непрезентабельном виде.

Ксерокс или принтер дают возможность многим учителям – к сожалению, далеко не всем! – сделать процесс обучения русскому языку более живым и эффективным.

Там теперь тоже ночь, но беззвучная, пылающая огнями созвездий, пахнущая не бензиновым чадом и пороховыми газами - может быть, следует говорить «взрывными» газами, - а устоявшейся в лесных озерах глубокой водой и хвоей можжевельника.

Тряский «автобус», а проще говоря, раздолбанный ЗИС-5 с огромной зеленой фанерной будкой вместо кузова, в которой были прорезаны по бокам два больших окна и вставлены стекла – вероятно, из разбитого троллейбуса, о чем свидетельствовал и десяток обшарпанных сидений, втиснутых в этот «салон», – натужно поскрипывая, вез Витьку Мальцева по утренней, еще припорошенной колючим снежком Москве.

В последних трех предложениях, согласно правилу (если внутри вставной конструкции должны быть запятые, они сохраняются) вводное словосочетание стоит в начале вводной конструкции и выделяется запятой.

Так почему же

в предложении *Женщины – красивые по крайней мере – редко бывают просты в общении.* вводное по *крайней мере* не отделяется запятой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вводное слово, входящее в состав обособленной конструкции, не отделяется запятыми от этой конструкции, если стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, а выделяется, когда стоит в середине обособленного оборота

Comment: но вставка - это обособленная конструкция, то есть не обособленный ЧЛЕН ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ. Вставное предложение - не член предложения.

Многие студенты – в частности, граждане других стран СНГ – могли бы получать целевые стипендии от потенциальных работодателей.

Comment: Ксерокс или принтер дают возможность многим учителям – к сожалению, далеко не всем! – сделать процесс обучения русскому языку более живым и эффективным.

Comment: В приведенном Вами примере слова "в частности граждане других сстран СНГ" - это обычный присоединительный обособленный член предложения. Откройте Розенталя: у него в учебнике даже параграф так называется "Обособленные уточняющие,присоединительные и пояснительные члены предложения". И вообще,категория обособления всегда связывается с понятием члена предложения. У Розенталя есть там же и правило о запятой для вводного слова, входящего в состав обособленного оборота.

Comment: Посмотрите Розенталя: он дает перечень вводных слов, которые не отделяются запятой от обособленного члена. Помню из этого перечня "в частности, например, главным образом"

Answer (score 6):

Сочетание по крайней мере пунктуационно **не выделяется,** если имеет значения **«не меньше чем», «самое меньшее»**: ***Савельич, насильственно разлученный со мною, утешался по крайней мере мыслию, что служит нареченной моей невесте (П.); По загоревшему лицу его можно было заключить, что он знал, что такое дым, если не пороховой, то по крайней мере табачный (Г.); Он неутомимо искал этих встреч, а она по крайней мере их не избегала (Л.); Раз двадцать по крайней мере и, кажется, без особенно важных причин он в одном пальто сбежал вниз к саням и вбежал опять наверх (Л.Т.); В настоящую минуту добросовестные и даровитые популяризаторы по крайней мере так же необходимы, как оригинальные мыслители и самостоятельные исследователи (Д.П.); По крайней мере буду знать, что я буду служить в русской армии (Булг.); Лошади с трудом тащили громоздкий дилижанс по песку глубиной по крайней мере в три четверти аршина (Кат.)***.[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

В Вашем примере выражение "по крайней мере" имеет значение "самое меньшее". Поэтому запятыми это выражение не выделяется.