# Подскажите причину и значение двоеточия в следующем предложении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Назовите причину и значение двоеточия в следующем предложении:

«У нас, несчастных людей, испорченных цивилизацией, не принято, чтобы подобные вам знатные обладатели огромных состояний — так по крайней мере уверяют: вы видите, я ни о чём не спрашиваю, а только повторяю молву, — так вот, у нас не принято, чтобы эти баловни фортуны теряли время на социальные проблемы, на философские мечтания, созданные разве что для утешения тех, кому судьба отказала в земных благах».

Скажите также, почему не выделено запятыми *по крайней мере*?

Comment: Это А.Дюма, не так ли? Постеснялись указать источник?

Comment: По поводу вводных слов "по крайней мере" см. ответ здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/12507/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Мне это двоеточие кажется какой-то ошибкой. Я бы поставил скобки: **так по крайней мере уверяют (вы видите, я ни о чём не спрашиваю, а только повторяю молву)**

Comment: @М_Г Да. Дюма, «Граф Монте Кристо».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Почему стоит двоеточие**

В предложении используются две  вставки **разного характера**,  при этом вторая ставка является **попутным самостоятельным замечанием** и ее действительно надо бы  обособить скобками.

В тексте же представлена одна вставка, причем вторая ее часть как бы поясняет первую (**отсюда следует двоеточие)**.  Но пояснительные отношения там  вряд ли присутствуют, это именно две разные вставки.

Поэтому двоеточие желательно бы убрать и  использовать скобки, как уже было сказано.

2) Обособление выражения ***по крайней мере***

Сочетание ***по крайней мере*** может быть:  (1) обособленным вводным словом, выражающим уверенность говорящего, или (2)необособленным наречием со значением ***как минимум***. Однако в художественной литературе оно часто **не обособляется и в первом значении**, особенно в распространенных предложениях.

Тогда получился бы вариант, удобный для чтения и не перегруженный лишними запятыми:

У нас, несчастных людей, испорченных цивилизацией, не принято, чтобы подобные вам знатные обладатели огромных состояний — **так по крайней мере уверяют (вы видите, я ни о чём не спрашиваю, а только повторяю молву),** — так вот, у нас не принято...